# calling for javascript function in php form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using a contact form on my website and I want it to use a javascript function to use a popup box to tell the user that they have not filled all fields. I have this code:

```
    <?php
  $action=$_REQUEST['action'];
  if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */
      {
      ?>
      <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
      *Name:<br>
      <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br><br>
      *Email:<br>
      <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br><br>
      *Message:<br>
      <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Send email"/>
      </form>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      function requiredFields() {
          alert("Please fill in all fields!");
      }
      <?php
      }
  else                /* send the submitted data */
      {
      $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
      $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
      $message=$_REQUEST['message'];
      if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message==""))
          {
          echo "requiredFields();";
          }
      else{
          $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
          $subject="Message sent using your contact form";
          mail("email@email.com", $subject, $message, $from);
          echo "Email sent!";
          }
      }
  ?>
      </script>
```

However, the website displays this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function requiredfields() in /home/a8502709/public_html/test/contact.php on line 46
```

The line above is the line that it echoes the calling for the function. How can I properly call the function in echo?

Comment: calling `java script` function through `php` code is not possible(server-side-client-side). So you have to apply some other way. possibility is `ajax` only if you want to show pop-up.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't quote your `echo` output:

```
echo requiredFields();;
```

It should be:

```
echo "requiredFields();";
```

Otherwise you're telling *PHP* to execute the `requiredFields()` function, which *doesn't exist* in PHP.  Hence the error.  Your intent here is to tell the JavaScript on the rendered page to execute the function.  So as far as PHP is concerned you're just outputting a string to the page.

---

Note also that this is a syntax error:

```
echo "Email sent!";
```

What this will do is emit the following to the JavaScript in your `<script>` block:

```
Email sent!
```

Which, of course, isn't valid JavaScript.  You probably meant to output that somewhere else in the page.

---

**Edit:** You also seem to have a significant logical error in your code.  If you remove the unrelated lines, your structure is essentially this:

```
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */
{
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
<?php
} else {
    echo "requiredFields();";
}
?>
</script>
```

So... You only *open* the `<script>` tag in the `if` block, but you *use* that tag in the `else` block.  By definition both can't execute.  Only one or the other.  So you're going to have to restructure this a bit.

Maybe close the `<script>` tag in the `if` block too, and then open another one in the `else` block?  Or have multiple `if/else` blocks for the HTML and for the JavaScript?  There are a couple of different ways to structure this.  But you should see what I'm talking about when you view the page source in your browser.  You'll see that, in the event of the `else` block, you're never creating a `<script type="text/javascript">` line and therefore aren't actually executing any JavaScript.

Though, thinking about this some more, it doesn't make sense at all to have the JavaScript start in the `if` block.  Since *only* the `else` block uses it.  You can't define the function in the `if` and then try to use it in the `else` because, again, by definition only one or the other would execute.  Maybe just move all of the JavaScript to the `else`:

```
<?php
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */
{
?>
  <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
  *Name:<br>
  <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br><br>
  *Email:<br>
  <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br><br>
  *Message:<br>
  <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Send email"/>
  </form>
<?php
}
else                /* send the submitted data */
{
?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function requiredFields() {
      alert("Please fill in all fields!");
  }
<?php
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $message=$_REQUEST['message'];
    if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message==""))
    {
        echo "requiredFields();";
    }
    else
    {
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
        $subject="Message sent using your contact form";
        mail("email@email.com", $subject, $message, $from);
        echo "alert('Email sent!')";
    }
?>
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Honestly, this mix of PHP/HTML/JavaScript you have here is a little confusing.  Which isn't making this any easier for you.  You'll probably want to re-structure this a bit once you get it at least working.

Comment: I tried that but it just prints "requiredFields(); " on the page

Comment: @D.Lin: That's exactly the point.  By outputting `requiredFields();` to the page in that `<script>` tag, that's how you'd get the JavaScript to execute that function.  Unless you mean it's actually rendering that text visibly on the page.  If that's the case, then your code is different from what you're showing in the question.

Comment: Its actually making "requiredFields();" visible on the page. I just editted my post to show the whole code instead of just a snippet.

Comment: @D.Lin: What is the actual client-side code being sent in the page source?  What you're describing doesn't sound possible with the code shown.  Something else must be wrong.  Text inside of a `<script>` tag isn't shown on the page.  It's JavaScript code.

Comment: but thats really my code that i'm using. ive been trying to figure it out for a while..

Comment: @D.Lin: You're going to have to debug this a little more than.  Start by examining the page source in the browser.  Your `<script>` tag placement doesn't match the behavior you're describing.

Comment: @D.Lin: Answer updated, that should do the trick.  You have some logical errors likely due to this confusing mix of three different programming languages stuffed together.  Even if it ends up being more code, you'll probably want to separate all of this a lot more so that it's more readable and easier to follow.

Comment: thank you. that does make it alert the user. how do i make it so the form shows up again? like redirect the user back to the page "contact.php"

Comment: i tried using header directly under the requiredFields() function, but then the alert doesn't put up anymore

Comment: nevermind i got it. i'm using window.location in my javascript function